# Python Pandas Dataframes Dtypes are Fake?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm a little baffled over the problem I'm having.  I have always been able to sum and slice dataframe columns.  Here's the dataframe I'm playing with:

```
In [24]: df2.dtypes
Out[24]:
day             object
imps            object
clicks         float64
total_convs    float64
revenue        float64
cost           float64
rpm            float64
dtype: object
```

Now, when I try this:

```
total_imps   =  sum(list(df1['imps']))
```

I get a TypeError.  I've always been able to slice and dice dataframes, so I'm wondering if the csv file I'm pulling this dataframe from is just weird somehow.  I've tried:

```
df2 = df2.astype(float)
```

but in this case the 'day' column won't convert.  I've also tried:

```
df2[['imps','clicks','total_convs','revenue','cost']] = df2[['imps','clicks','total_convs','revenue','cost']].astype(float)
```

which gets me:

```
In [24]: df2.dtypes
Out[24]:
day             object
imps           float64
clicks         float64
total_convs    float64
revenue        float64
cost           float64
rpm            float64
dtype: object
```

Which is nice, but I still can't sum up any of it.  Doing so would just return the TypeError again.  At this point, I mind as well pull out the ti-83 and just add these numbers by hand but I need this for automation moving forward.

Comment: can u show part of the file u r reading and how u r doing it (and the contents of that column), and pandas versions

Comment: I think jumping to a TI-83 might be just a *tad* premature. Can show `df2.head()` and/or `df.head()`?

Comment: As we like to say, "stacktrace or it didn't happen"

Answer (score -1):

For some glorious reason, this works:

```
ll = list(df2['imps'])
total_imps = sum(ll)
```

but this doesn't:

```
total_imps = sum(list(df2['imps'])
```

Hooray pandas.

Comment: That seems unlikely.  Could you edit to include a full transcript?  (For example, you're missing a closing `)`, so this can't be *exactly* what you did.)